# Realm map clustering

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

To create your own data to present in `realm map` you need Model which looks like from example :

```
public class ABFRestaurantObject: Object {
    public dynamic var businessId: String?
    public dynamic var name: String?
    public dynamic var address: String?
    public dynamic var city: String?
    public dynamic var state: String?
    public dynamic var postalCode: String?
    public dynamic var latitude: Double = 37.7859547
    public dynamic var longitude: Double = -122.4024658
    public dynamic var phoneNumber: String?
    public let violations = List<ABFViolationObject>()
    public let inspections = List<ABFInspectionObject>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "businessId"
    }
}
```

What means this `primaryKey` ? Then how could I load my own data into it ? Of course omitting fact that you have to create your own model with custom propertiese ?

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

I am using Realm map kit clustering

I've created model :

```
class Test: Object {

   public dynamic var id = 0
   public dynamic var latitude = 45.0889
   public dynamic var longitude = 54.1565

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}


}
```

Then in my map controller I've added following functions and declarations :

```
var positions = try! Realm().objects(Test.self)
    var position:Test!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addNewVehicle()
        populateMap()
    }

func addNewPosition() {
    let realm = try! Realm() // 1

    try! realm.write { // 2
        let newPos = Test() // 3

        newPos.latitude = 50.060363
        newPos.longitude = 19.939983
        realm.add(newPos) // 5
        self.position = newPos // 6
    }
}

func populateMap() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations) // 1

    let positions = try! Realm().objects(Test.self) // 2

    // Create annotations for each one
    for pos in positions { // 3
        let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
        let pin = MapPin(coordinate: coord, title: "asd", subtitle: "asd")
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin) // 4
    }
}
```

And at the end simple class fro creating pins :

```
class MapPin : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}
```

I would like to create few random pins and see if clustring works. 
Atm i am getting an error in line :

```
safeObject->_coordinate = coordinate;
```

Thread 9: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x40)

```
po positions
Results<Test> (
    [0] Test {
        latitude = 50.060363;
        longitude = 19.939983;
    },
    [1] Test {
        latitude = 50.060363;
        longitude = 19.939983;
    },
    [2] Test {
        latitude = 50.060363;
        longitude = 19.939983;
    }
)
```

Then I've added as well to my `AppDelegate.swift` to the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
 let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.default()
        config.schemaVersion = 1
        config.migrationBlock = { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
        }
        RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefault(config)
```

Error: "Primary key property 'Test.id' has duplicate values after migration."

Comment: print please elements from Realm. They are not empty ?

Comment: already have 3 elements

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/issues/15

Comment: I've did update on my new Test model, added new method into appdelegate and got a new error ;/

Comment: it should be unique. Id already is used in Test

Comment: I do not get it, id docs the `primaryKey` have the same propertie in the model as a key

Comment: change it from id to testId and try

Comment: whenever i change just propertie to other the return of the `primaryKey()` it says that key with X does not exist and whenever i make them same it says that has duplicate values

Answer (score 2):

From the REALM documentation.

> Override Object.primaryKey() to set the model’s primary key. Declaring
>   a primary key allows objects to be looked up and updated efficiently
>   and enforces uniqueness for each value. Once an object with a primary
>   key is added to a Realm, the primary key cannot be changed.

If you would like to create own Realm model simply create class with `Object` extension.

Example:

```
class User: Object {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var email = ""
}
```

Comment: Al'right! Then which steps I should follow to add my own data to the map ? Do i have to save data into realm DB in the first step and then load it through the model ?

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown it's not completely clear what location library you use, but if you want to persist your data between app launches you should store it in database. Please see docs and example apps at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#examples to learn more how to work with Realm.